# Import changes from github gist to repository

Tags: git, github, codepen

I have a gist:
https://gist.github.com/Microflow/f91c2ce2bac17b1fb8a5d303834da28c

I used Github's import feature to turn the gist into a new repository.
https://github.com/Microflow/Hyperloop1

*

I know I can use git to push/pull new changes from my local computer, but I want to pull new changes in to my repo from a new gist. I work on many different computers, and don't have git installed on all of them.

Can I pull changes from a gist to a github repo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GitHub does not provide this natively. On your other computers you might want to just download the gist (or the CodePen that you built this with) on them as you make edits, or consider installing git, installing the [GitHub Desktop](https://desktop.github.com/) software, or by manually editing the files in the GitHub repo and pasting in the gist values (screenshot below, it's the pencil icon).

[image: Screenshot of GitHub edit button]

Comment: That's probably the best way forward. Or I will use a cloud IDE again...